# IllegalMonitorStateException while releasing lock in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, concurrency, ignite, distributed-caching

I am using ignite 2.8.1  I have ignite lock that is inside some cron, I use it to run my processing only on single server node.I have 3 server nodes in my app.

And today I've seen some exceptions. Could you explain how it could happens? It seems it happens while unlock(), but it is strange how it could not own the lock if is inside tryLock() ?

```
<ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-volatile-ds-group> Lock.unlock() is called in illegal state [callerNodeId=ee0de9a9-5a13-4971-a744-dcc5087fd287, ownerNodeId=a2bba513-9ed7-4dc3-beea-574bf46f0034, callerThreadId=674, ownerThreadId=672, lockState=1]
```

ant trace:

```
        java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheLockImpl$Sync.tryRelease(GridCacheLockImpl.java:446) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261) at 
    org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheLockImpl.unlock(GridCacheLockImpl.java:1258) at com.sa.sm.vp.service.LockUtil.unlock(LockUtil.java:35) at 
com.sa.sm.vp.service.content.SessionExpirator.triggerExpirationEvent(SessionExpirator.java:78) at 
 
com.sa.sm.vp.service.content.SessionExpirator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ac2d1b1f.invoke(<generated>) at
     org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) at 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) at 
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) at 
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) at 
    org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88) at 
    io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.scheduled.ScheduledAspect.traceBackgroundThread(ScheduledAspect.java:57) at 
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644) at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633) at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroun
```

code:

```
private IgniteSpringBean igniteSpringBean;

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 20000, fixedDelay = 4000)
    @Timed
    public void triggerExpirationEvent() {
        IgniteLock lock = igniteSpringBean.reentrantLock("PLAYBACK_SESSION", true, true, true);
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                        // do my work in separate thread
                       // timeout
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        log.warn("Failed to sleep ", e);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling unlock() in the same thread as lock()? Your code implies so but the exceptions suggest otherwise.

Comment: it is exactly like in my code, I call unlock in finally only if tryLock is true

Comment: Can you prepare a small reproducer project which exhibits this behavior, put it on github somewhere?